# htmlcommentbox on blogger, how to treat ?m=0 and ?m=0 as normal post (.html)

Tags: comments, blogger, blogspot

I found a fast and wordpress like comments system for blogger.

It's actually www.htmlcommentbox.com

But it treat ?m=0   and ?m=1 as different pages. So technically I have 3 comment box for a single post.

this is the script (it may not show as text here)

```
    <!-- begin comments -->

 <div id="Quickfever comments">
 <div id="HCB_comment_box"><a href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com">Please wait,</a> we're loading comments...</div>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/skins/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap.css?v=0" />
 <script type="text/javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={};} (function(){var s=document.createElement("script"), l=hcb_user.PAGE || (""+window.location).replace(/'/g,"%27"), h="//www.htmlcommentbox.com";s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttribute("src", h+"/jread?page="+encodeURIComponent(l).replace("+","%2B")+"&mod=%241%24wq1rdBcg%242.J.aNtE5me1DUGfmwzpF1"+"&opts=18398&num=10&ts=1454419699649");if (typeof s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})(); /*-->*/ </script>
<!-- end comments -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <!-- begin comments -->
  <div id="Quickfever comments">
  <div id="HCB_comment_box"><a href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com">Please wait,</a> we're loading comments...</div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/skins/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap.css?v=0" />
  <script>var commentsCanonicalPostUrl = &#39;<data:post.canonicalUrl/>&#39;;</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={};} (function(){var s=document.createElement("script"), l=hcb_user.PAGE || (""+commentsCanonicalPostUrl).replace(/'/g,"%27"), h="//www.htmlcommentbox.com";s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttribute("src", h+"/jread?page="+encodeURIComponent(l).replace("+","%2B")+"&mod=%241%24wq1rdBcg%242.J.aNtE5me1DUGfmwzpF1"+"&opts=18398&num=10&ts=1454419699649");if (typeof s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})(); /*-->*/ </script>
<!-- end comments -->
```

Note that codes like this one should be added in Template > Edit HTML rather than in each individual blog post.